# What's wrong with MATLAB's histogram equalization?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, histogram, scikit-image

I'm trying to do a histogram equalization on a 16-bit gray scale image, the original histogram is shown below, which has ~25000 gray levels:
[image: Histogram of original image]

I was first using MATLAB but for some reason the total levels was significantly reduced in the output (only 21!). I tried to manually assign a bin number of 20,000 but the output level is still minimal (67). 
[image: Histogram equalization from MATLAB]

I then tried Scikit-Image in Python and everything works as expected -- output now has 16,500 levels and the histogram is pretty much flat.
[image]

Here's the MATLAB command:

```matlab
J = histeq(I,2e4);
```

Here's Python command:

```py
img_eq_sk = exposure.equalize_hist(img_16bit)
```

Since histogram equalization is such a basic operation, I would expect MATLAB and Python behave similarly, but according to this MATLAB's result isn't even nearly as good as Skimage's.

Comment: Does the same happen if you cast the input image to double?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Actually there's a minor improvement if I cast it to double, the gray level of equalized image now increased to 34(default) and 132 (2e4 bins)

Comment: I think the main difference is that we use floats throughout the process in scikit-image, while I imagine Matlab rounds to uint8 immediately. I did a comparison between the two after a user's bug report here: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2677#issuecomment-309717979

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think it exactly explains my concern. Looks like MATLAB introduced a lot of rounding errors during this process; as you said, we don't get so few levels even if placing Skimage result into 255 bins .

Answer (score 0):

I can verify what you're seeing:

```matlab
I = uint16(randn(1000,1000) * 5000 + 3e4);
imhist(I)
size(unique(I(:))) % returns: 31290 unique gray values

J = histeq(I,8e5); % actually uses only 6.5e4, the max for uint16
imhist(J)
size(unique(J(:))) % returns: 158 unique gray values

K = histeq(im2double(I),8e5);
imhist(K)
size(unique(K(:))) % returns: 175 unique gray values
```

When the input values need to be stretched significantly, many different gray values end up in the same output bin, and many output bins remain empty.

When looking at the result with a double image (`K` in the code above) one can see how the number of unique output gray levels increases as one increases the parameter to `histeq`.

That is, the output is quantized to a set number of values (800,000 in the example above), not only the input. So if many of those output bins are empty, there will be very few distinct output gray values.

There is no need to implement histogram equalization this way, as can be seen by the Python implementation used in the OP. However, it doesn't seem that this implementation is wrong, it just quantizes the output unnecessarily.

<opinion> However, since histogram equalization is something useful only for visualization, and since for visualization one doesn't need more than about 100 distinct gray values (we can't distinguish more than that anyway), the output quantization should not be a major problem. If you're using histogram equalization for anything else (i.e. image analysis and quantification) you're doing it wrong! </opinion>

Comment: Regarding the comment on visual effect, there's actually strong degradation of the visual quality of the image after hist equalization using MATLAB -- large patches of flat region just like you don't have enough bit depth. I am actually using it for image analysis as all the important features are buried in the dark regions, so I can't even see every change I apply unless I equalize the histogram in the first place.

Comment: @Akahs: Don’t use histogram equalization for image analysis. Use a contrast enhancing method where you know and control what happens to your gray values. After histogram equalization you no longer know the relationship between original and output data. It also  changes if you crop your image slightly differently or mask out a different portion.

Comment: That's fair. By other known contrast enhancing method, you mean something like normalization and gamma correction?

Comment: @Akahs: You can apply any transfer function you want, as long as that transfer function doesn't depend on the input data. That way, different images are treated exactly the same. A gamma correction, a linear scaling, an offset correction, these are all normal things to apply before analysis. Normalization like they do in machine learning works only if you determine a normalization from some data, then apply the exact same scaling to all the data. You cannot normalize each image independently, because then they'll be scaled differently and no longer comparable.